# Typescript: Override variable previously declared

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a Typescript declaration file, and one of the types for the library is called 'Image', as shown below.

```
declare class Image {
    static fromData(data: Data): Image;
    static fromFile(filePath: string): Image;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error saying that 'Image' is a duplicate identifier, and I can't use it.

```
../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16908:13 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Image'.

16908 declare var Image: {
                  ~~~~~

  index.d.ts:2:15
    2 declare class Image {
                    ~~~~~
    'Image' was also declared here.
```

Is there any way I can override the previous declaration (which isn't even a type, just a constructor for `HTMLImageElement`) and repurpose it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why you should always prefer exported types over ambient ones (global, stored in *.d.ts files).

Just create a file e.g. types.ts with the following contents

```
export class Image {
    static fromData(data: Data): Image;
    static fromFile(filePath: string): Image;
}
```

then import it as usual `import {Image} from './types'`

if you still have a conflict, you can do this `import {Image as MyImage} from './types'`